# Linux - concatenate every line of a text file with an argument passed into a function

Tags: linux, bash, concatenation

I have a .sh function that accepts a path for an argument $1.
I have a text file with file names.
I need to concatenate the value of $1 to every line of my text file

```
txt file:
   file1.jpg
   file2.jpg

argument:
   $1 = path/
   $2 = to/dir/
```

Goal

```
txt file:
    path/to/dir/file1.jpg
    path/to/dir/file2.jpg
```

Comment: Is there anything else on the lines in the text file? If not then `sed -e "s/^/$1\//" file` should do what you want.

Comment: @EtanReisner Make it an answer

Comment: SO CLOSE! I forgot a detail. I have two parts to the path... $1/$2. How would I do that?  THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still assuming that the lines in the file contain *only* the partial path data and just extending the idea in my comment you get:

```
sed -e "s!^!$1/$2/!" file
```

Comment: perfect! And if I want that to output to a new file I use > new/file? @Etan Reisner - thank you for the good and fast work!

Comment: @AshBrad Yes. Or `-i` to have sed operate in place.